# Programmatically switching audio driver in Windows?

Tags: windows, audio, driver

I've been working on a program for a specific audio device. This device comes with its own official drivers, but it also supports the generic USB audio driver supplied by Windows. I've found that my program only works on the generic driver.

Rather than asking the user to switch their audio driver, is there any way I can programmatically switch to the generic audio driver at runtime, and then switch back when the program is closed?

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing is using [DevCon](https://superuser.com/questions/1002950/quick-method-to-install-devcon-exe), a command line utility that's included with the Windows Driver Kit and can replace the functionality of the device manager. Then I just used the [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) function to launch a batch file with the [DevCon Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-update) command when I wanted to load the first driver, and used a second batch file to reinstall the original driver when I wanted to switch back, using the exact same method.

I'm pretty sure you can also utilize native Windows functions to achieve this (the DevCon source code is available), but this method was easier for me.